# How do you handle a variable number of MVC routes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, url-routing

I note this intriguing bit in ASP.NET MVC:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

I'd like to map {*pathInfo} into a route.

Something like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "area/{*pathInfo}",
   "{controller}/{action}/{id}",parameters
   new { controller = "Area", action = "Index", id = ??? } 
);
```

but how do I pass in the variable "foo/bar/rab/oof" from mydomain.com/area/foo/bar/rab/oof? Either passing the entire bit as a string or as a collection would be fine with me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which MVC version are you using?  The route name should be the first parameter to MapRoute() as I remember in MCV Beta.  Anyway, given your goal of capturing the path, I would do s/t like:

```
routes.MapRoute("AreaRoute", "Area/{*values}", new {controller = "Area", action = "Index"}       );
```

And in the Area controller:

```
// "value" argument is the string after Area/, i.e. "foo/bar/rab/oof" in your example
public string Index(string values)  
{  
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'm using RC2. I'll test this out and get back to you.

Comment: Once I made sure this pattern was registered BEFORE the default route pattern (ready about that elsewhere but completely forgot about it while trying this!) your solution worked perfectly. Thanks much.

Comment: It did help, for /area/1 and /area/1/2 .. but once I tried /area/1/2/3 as my url pattern, all subsequent requests for that page (i.e., /Scripts/jquery.js) were ALSO being sent to my Area controller. I tried putting in an explicit pattern above this one, and it still happens. Any further ideas?

Comment: I figured it out right after asking. My script reference was "../../Scripts/foo.js". Once I did "/Scripts/foo.js" it started working again. There's an issue in the routing logic because the behavior varies with context, and shouldn't match Scripts/* for Area/* though.